# Ubuntu 17 - Suspend and hibernate not working, Computer just shuts down

Tags: suspend, 17.04, hibernate

Im using dual boot with Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu 17.04. Whenever I press suspend or hibernate the computer just shuts down and loses any unsaved data. This is a problem since im a developer and don't want to lose my codes accidentally.

Im using an acer laptop with 8gb of Ram. I have swap with size of 16gb.

Comment: The same problem here, but I have bigger RAM (32) and smaller swap (8).

Comment: Hibernation is a severe problem when using linux. Usually one of the drivers do not shut down correctly. The OS will flag this, grub recognizes it and a new start will take place. You may test your hardware by using the tests mentioned here: <https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/swsusp.txt>. It helped me to find the culprit that prevented a resume from hibernate.